# Remote desktop software where every remote client has their individual desktop session of the host, so that each client can work independently

Tags: windows, remote-access, remote-desktop, multi-user

**Microsoft's RDP** (Remote Desktop Protocol) supports multi user/session remote access, where every remote client has their **individual desktop session** of the host system, so that each client **can work independently** without interfering others (*This is what I want*)

Alternatives such as **TeamViewer**,  **VNC variants**, etc do not support this (multi user/session) feature, and **only support screen-sharing** (*which is good for remote assistance, but this is not what I want*)

**Please do correct me if I am wrong anywhere in above 2 statements**

My Question is "**Is there an alternative to Microsoft's RDP with multi user/session remote access**"

PS: 
I am asking this question in the context of **Windows-only environment** (both for client & host), not linux or Mac

Comment: With VNC every client has an individual session (at least on Linux), but AFAIK you must start the session manually on the server...

Comment: Have you looked at Citrix ?  It was the basis for Terminal Services.

Comment: IMHO Windows 7 supports only 1 user and the server versions can have multiple sessions at once. At least for the officially supported version. You can [enable multiple sessions](http://www.blogsdna.com/2336/enable-multiple-user-accessconcurrent-user-sessions-for-remote-desktop-on-windows-7.htm) at your own risk, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [FreeRDP](http://www.freerdp.com/), which is a free remote desktop protocol library and clients. Check out the [GitHub page](https://github.com/FreeRDP/FreeRDP).

Install via Brew: `brew install freerdp`.

If it doesn't support the feature you need, you may create [a new feature request](https://github.com/FreeRDP/FreeRDP/issues).

Comment: Hi, would you mind inserting an excerpt from the product's documentation where it says explicitly that **every remote client has their individual desktop session of the host system, so that each client can work independently without interfering others**? If not we will have to remove this answer, as this feature is the whole point of the question. Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Way late to this party, but NComputing's vSpace Pro does exactly what you're looking for - multiple virtual sessions on 1 server that are independent of one another. They all use the same base OS and application set, but each user is independent.

Comment: Hi, would you mind inserting an excerpt from the product's documentation where it says explicitly that **every remote client has their individual desktop session of the host system, so that each client can work independently without interfering others**? If not we will have to remove this answer, as this feature is the whole point of the question. Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Before Windows had RDP, Citrix was THE remote desktop (or application) leader - https://www.citrix.com/digital-workspace/virtualization-mobile-productivity.html

Comment: Hi, would you mind inserting an excerpt from the product's documentation where it says explicitly that **every remote client has their individual desktop session of the host system, so that each client can work independently without interfering others**? If not we will have to remove this answer, as this feature is the whole point of the question. Thanks! :-)